# Change Timer Callback Function NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

Is it possible to change the callback function of a running timer? I want to update what the callback function is for the timer without reseting the time.

Given:

```
let timerExample = timers.setInterval(function() { console.log("setTimeout: It's been one second!"); }, 10000);
```

Possible:

```
timerExample.callBack = function() { console.log('some new callback') };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes like this;

```
cb = function(){
   console.log("setTimeout: It's been one second!");
};


let timerExample = timers.setInterval(function() { cb(); }, 10000);
//
// If we change our cb to a new function it will be called in our timer
//
cb =  function() { console.log('some new callback') };
```

What we are doing is calling a callback function cb from within our timer function and so if we change it on-the-fly the timer event will call our new function.